# How to use ajax in entity reference custom form to display no entity error in drupal 8?

Tags: 8, entities, ajax

I created a custom form on entity autocomplete called items like below,

```
$form['items'] = array(
   '#title' => $this->t('Items'),
   '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
   '#target_type' => 'node',
   '#selection_handler' => 'default',
   '#selection_settings' => array(
       'target_bundles' => array('items'),
    ),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#placeholder' => 'Type items',
);
```

It is working fine. If i type item which is not in the items list the page gets refreshed and displayed the message `There are no entities matching`.

Here i want to display this error message without page loading. I `tried using ajax` like this,

```
'#ajax' => [
    'callback' => '::updateDestinataire',
 ],
```

But it didn't work for me. How can i solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This error message is provided by `\Drupal\Core\Entity\Element\EntityAutocomplete::matchEntityByTitle()` called by `\Drupal\Core\Entity\Element\EntityAutocomplete::validateEntityAutocomplete()` method and is invoked at element validation (explained later) so it cannot be overriden using AJAX API. To do so, you can implement one of the following:

**Extend the element and create your own and override that particular method**

Assuming your new form element is as follows:

*../my_module/src/Element/CustomEntityAutocomplete.php*

```
namespace Drupal\my_nodule\Element;

/**
 * My custom autocomplete.
 *
 * @FormElement("custom_entity_autocomplete")
 */
class CustomEntityAutocomplete extends EntityAutocomplete {
  ...
  // Override the ::matchEntityByTitle method with the message you want.
}
```

You change your form render array to:

```
$form['items'] = array(
   '#title' => $this->t('Items'),
   '#type' => 'custom_entity_autocomplete',
   '#target_type' => 'node',
   '#selection_handler' => 'default',
   '#selection_settings' => array(
       'target_bundles' => array('items'),
    ),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#placeholder' => 'Type items',
);
```

Clear the cache and everything should work as expected. Mind the namespace and your class path so the discovery work properly.

**or... Provide only the validate method**

I personally prefer the latter but you have this choice too.

The `\Drupal\Core\Entity\Element\EntityAutocomplete::getInfo()` is implemented as follows:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getInfo() {
  $info = parent::getInfo();
  $class = get_class($this);
  ....
  $info['#element_validate'] = [[$class, 'validateEntityAutocomplete']];
  array_unshift($info['#process'], [$class, 'processEntityAutocomplete']);

  return $info;
}
```

If you look closer you could see that the validate is referenced there so, you could override it on your render array.

```
$form['items'] = array(
   '#title' => $this->t('Items'),
   '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
   '#element_validate' => [['\Drupal\my_module\MyAwesomeClass::validateEntityAutocomplete']],
   '#target_type' => 'node',
   '#selection_handler' => 'default',
   '#selection_settings' => array(
       'target_bundles' => array('items'),
    ),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#placeholder' => 'Type items',
);
```

This way you could validate your entity autocomplete whatever you please.